# How to implement HTML component based architecture without using angular.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Is their a built-in feature or using a JS library to create a component based application just like Angular, but using HTML5, JS and Jquery in order to avoid boiler plate code in every page of the website and only import the link to the page that contains a specific component?

Comment: This question is vague. Could you be more specific/show an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), but it's still bleeding edge, so you'll want to use a [polyfill](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills). [hyperHTML and lit-html](https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/fadcc419f5ccaae92bc167d8ff5c611b) are relatively tiny libraries that integrate well with Web Components. [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) is a larger one.

Comment: We have a title and navigation bar, side navigation bar and a footer for almost every page of the web app. Rather than adding the code in every page that is present, i would like to give a small custom tag or something similar that represents these specific (title navigation, side navigation and footer) components. I do not want to add a large framework for just this one task. So, is there any small library that is just specific to implement this component style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of frameworks and libraries implement the component architecture

You can use something native like

> [Web Componetns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

or use framework that makes using reusable components and web components is so easy like

> [PolymerJS](https://www.polymer-project.org/)

or use libraries and frameworks that gives you more power and efficiency

> [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/)  [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/)

choose what will work best for you .